# How to identify partial duplicates of rows in R

Tags: r

I would like to identify "partial" matches of rows in a dataframe. Specifically, I want to create a new column with a value of `1` if a particular row in a dataframe has duplicate row somewhere else in the dataframe based on a match between a subset of columns. An added complexity is that one of the columns in the dataframe is numeric and I want to match if the absolute values match. Here is example data followed by an example of my desired output.

```
name<-c("Richard Nixon", "Bill Clinton", "George Bush", "Richard Nixon")
state<-c("California", "Indiana", "Florida", "California")
num<-c("-258", "123", "42", "258")
date<-c("day 2", "day 15", "day 3","day 45")
(df<-as.data.frame(cbind(name,state,num, date)))
           name      state  num   date
1 Richard Nixon California -258  day 2
2  Bill Clinton    Indiana  123 day 15
3   George Bush    Florida   42  day 3
4 Richard Nixon California  258 day 45
```

What I'm hoping to acquire is the following dataframe:

```
           name      state  num   date newcol
1 Richard Nixon California -258  day 2 1
2  Bill Clinton    Indiana  123 day 15 0
3   George Bush    Florida   42  day 3 0
4 Richard Nixon California  258 day 45 1
```

Notice that rows 1 and 2 match along the `name` and `state` column and their absolute values match in the `num` column, resulting in a `1` in the added `newcol` column for both those rows, while the remaining rows have no such match and thus are valued at `0`.

I tried the following but to no avail:

```
df$num<-as.numeric(df$num)
which(duplicated(df[c('name', 'state',abs('num'))]),)

Error in abs("num") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Of course that does not work because of the `abs()`

Comment: The reason you're getting the error is you are trying to take the `abs()` of the character string "num"

Comment: Yes I know that (pretty obvious), I figured that would not work, just showing what I had attempted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
df$absnum = abs(as.numeric(as.character(df$num)))
df$newcol = duplicated(df[,c('name','state', 'absnum')]) | 
  duplicated(df[,c('name','state', 'absnum')], fromLast = T)

#            name      state  num   date absnum newcol
# 1 Richard Nixon California -258  day 2    258   TRUE
# 2  Bill Clinton    Indiana  123 day 15    123  FALSE
# 3   George Bush    Florida   42  day 3     42  FALSE
# 4 Richard Nixon California  258 day 45    258   TRUE
```

If you really need `newcol` to be `1` or `0`, then you can convert it to integer using `as.integer`.  But in most cases it is best to keep boolean flags as logical types.

Comment: Thanks @dww , I have an added complexity that I've posted here if you're interested in tackling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661698/how-to-identify-mirrored-duplicates-of-rows-in-r

Comment: basically its same question as here except that I want the match to return TRUE only if they match on their absolute values (for num) and NOT in their original values...