# How to identify mirrored duplicates of rows in R

Tags: r

In the following SO post [How to identify partial duplicates of rows in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661129/how-to-identify-partial-duplicates-of-rows-in-r#54661129), I asked how to get rid of partially duplicated rows. Here's what I asked:

**I would like to identify "partial" matches of rows in a dataframe. Specifically, I want to create a new column with a value of 1 if a particular row in a dataframe has duplicate row somewhere else in the dataframe based on a match between a subset of columns. An added complexity is that one of the columns in the dataframe is numeric and I want to match if the absolute values match.**

The issue is that I need to make sure that when a row is identified as partially duplicated, it is so ONLY if ONE of the columns that's part of the match is the mirror opposite value and not just a match on an absolute value. To make things clearer, here's the sample data from the previous post:

```
name<-c("Richard Nixon", "Bill Clinton", "George Bush", "Richard Nixon")
state<-c("California", "Indiana", "Florida", "California")
num<-c("-258", "123", "42", "258")
date<-c("day 2", "day 15", "day 3","day 45")
(df<-as.data.frame(cbind(name,state,num, date)))
           name      state  num   date
1 Richard Nixon California -258  day 2
2  Bill Clinton    Indiana  123 day 15
3   George Bush    Florida   42  day 3
4 Richard Nixon California  258 day 45
```

Here was the solution to my previous post:

```
df$absnum = abs(as.numeric(as.character(df$num)))
df$newcol = duplicated(df[,c('name','state', 'absnum')]) | 
  duplicated(df[,c('name','state', 'absnum')], fromLast = T)

#            name      state  num   date absnum newcol
# 1 Richard Nixon California -258  day 2    258   TRUE
# 2  Bill Clinton    Indiana  123 day 15    123  FALSE
# 3   George Bush    Florida   42  day 3     42  FALSE
# 4 Richard Nixon California  258 day 45    258   TRUE
```

Note that row 1 and row 4 are labeled `TRUE` under `newcol`, which is fine. And here is new sample data with the added complexity issue:

```
name<-c("Richard Nixon", "Bill Clinton", "George Bush", "Richard Nixon", "Bill 
Clinton")
state<-c("California", "Indiana", "Florida", "California", "Indiana")
num<-c("-258", "123", "42", "258", "123")
date<-c("day 2", "day 15", "day 3","day 45", "day 100")
(df<-as.data.frame(cbind(name,state,num, date)))

  name           state      num   date
1 Richard Nixon  California -258  day 2
2 Bill Clinton   Indiana    123   day 15
3 George Bush    Florida    42    day 3
4 Richard Nixon  California 258   day 45
5 Bill Clinton   Indiana    123   day 100
```

Note that observations 2 and 5 are partial duplicates but not in the same way as 1 and 4. I need to apply `TRUE` only to those observations in which their absolute values match BUT NOT their original values. So I want the result to return the following:

```
  name           state      num   date    newcol
1 Richard Nixon  California -258  day 2   TRUE
2 Bill Clinton   Indiana    123   day 15  FALSE
3 George Bush    Florida    42    day 3   FALSE
4 Richard Nixon  California 258   day 45  TRUE
5 Bill Clinton   Indiana    123   day 100 FALSE
```

The solution provided by the previous SO post would apply `TRUE` to rows 2 and 5 when I only would like this applied to rows 1 and 4.

Comment: do you always only have (at most) two entries per name and state? What do you do in scenarios where there are 3+? Do you compare entries 1 & 2, and then 2 & 3, and then 1 & 3?

Comment: @Chase I opened up a new SO question that tries to tackle this issue you mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665416/remove-partially-matched-rows-sequentially-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to convert the 'num' to `numeric` type first, create another column with `abs`olute values ('num1'), grouped by 'name', 'state', 'num1', `mutate` to create the bool column by checking the number of rows equal to 2 (`n() == 2`) and the number of distinct `sign` of 'num' greater than 1

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(num = as.numeric(num), num1 = abs(num)) %>% 
    group_by(name, state, num1) %>% 
    mutate(newcol = n() == 2 & n_distinct(sign(num)) > 1) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-num1)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  name          state        num date    newcol 
#  <chr>         <chr>      <dbl> <chr>   <lgl>
#1 Richard Nixon California  -258 day 2   TRUE 
#2 Bill Clinton  Indiana      123 day 15  FALSE
#3 George Bush   Florida       42 day 3   FALSE
#4 Richard Nixon California   258 day 45  TRUE 
#5 Bill Clinton  Indiana      123 day 100 FALSE
```

NOTE: `cbind` creates a `matrix` and `matrix` can have only single type.  Therefore, if there is any character column or element, the whole matrix becomes `character` class.  Wrapping it with `data.frame`, propagates that and can convert to `factor` (`stringsAsFactors = TRUE` - by default) or `character` (if we change it to `FALSE`)

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(name, state, num, date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: My apologies, it was fine. and thanks for your very thorough explanation.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian. I changed `n() == 2` based on your comments to @Chase

Comment: @In retrospect, I need some type of sequential process that identifies matched rows that are additive inverses of one another along the `num` variable. I opened up a new SO to that end, and i appreciate all the help , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665416/remove-partially-matched-rows-sequentially-in-r

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian. Thanks for the updating me.  I posted a solution in the link.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can use the same `duplicated` test as your linked question on 'partial' duplicates, but then exclude values that are the same

```
df$numnum = as.numeric(as.character(df$num))
df$absnum = abs(df$numnum)
df$newcol = (duplicated(df[,c('name','state', 'absnum')]) | 
  duplicated(df[,c('name','state', 'absnum')], fromLast = T)) &
  !(duplicated(df$numnum) | duplicated(df$numnum, fromLast = T))
#            name      state  num    date numnum absnum newcol
# 1 Richard Nixon California -258   day 2   -258    258   TRUE
# 2  Bill Clinton    Indiana  123  day 15    123    123  FALSE
# 3   George Bush    Florida   42   day 3     42     42  FALSE
# 4 Richard Nixon California  258  day 45    258    258   TRUE
# 5  Bill Clinton    Indiana  123 day 100    123    123  FALSE
```