# Removing pairs of additive inverses

Tags: r

This question is based off two previous questions I asked on SO, each more complex than the previous. In the previous post - [How to identify mirrored duplicates of rows in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661698/how-to-identify-mirrored-duplicates-of-rows-in-r/54661800?noredirect=1#comment96114863_54661800) -

I would like to identify "partial" matches of rows in a dataframe. Specifically, I want to create a new column with a value of TRUE if a particular row in a dataframe has duplicate row somewhere else in the dataframe based on a match between a subset of columns. An added complexity is that one of the columns in the dataframe is numeric and I want to match if the absolute values match. The issue is that I need to make sure that when a row is identified as partially duplicated, it is so ONLY if ONE of the columns that's part of the match is the mirror opposite (additive inverse) value and not just a match on an absolute value. Ultimately what I'm looking for are rows that are pairs of duplicates along 2 categorical variables and are additive inverses along a third numerical variable. To make things clearer, here's sample data:

```
name<-c("Richard Nixon", "Bill Clinton", "George Bush", "Richard Nixon", "Bill Clinton", "Richard Nixon", "Abe Lincoln","Richard Nixon", "Bill Clinton", "Richard Nixon")
state<-c("California", "Indiana", "Florida", "California", "Indiana", "California","Oregon","California", "Indiana", "California")
num<-c("-258", "123", "42", "258", "123", "-258", "87","258", "-123", "258")
date<-c("day 9", "day 2", "day 15", "day 3","day 45", "day 100", "day 99", "day 10", "day 11", "day 100")

(df <- data.frame(name, state, num, date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
            name      state  num    date
1  Richard Nixon California -258   day 9
2   Bill Clinton    Indiana  123   day 2
3    George Bush    Florida   42  day 15
4  Richard Nixon California  258   day 3
5   Bill Clinton    Indiana  123  day 45
6  Richard Nixon California -258 day 100
7    Abe Lincoln     Oregon   87  day 99
8  Richard Nixon California  258  day 10
9   Bill Clinton    Indiana -123  day 11
10 Richard Nixon California  258 day 100
```

If I were to run the excellent solution from the previous SO question I posted, it would result in the following

```
(df %>%
    mutate(num = as.numeric(num), num1 = abs(num)) %>% 
    group_by(name, state, num1) %>% 
    mutate(newcol = n() > 1 & n_distinct(sign(num)) > 1) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-num1)) %>%
    arrange(name)
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   name          state        num date    newcol
   <chr>         <chr>      <dbl> <chr>   <lgl> 
 1 Abe Lincoln   Oregon        87 day 99  FALSE 
 2 Bill Clinton  Indiana      123 day 2   TRUE  
 3 Bill Clinton  Indiana      123 day 45  TRUE  
 4 Bill Clinton  Indiana     -123 day 11  TRUE  
 5 George Bush   Florida       42 day 15  FALSE 
 6 Richard Nixon California  -258 day 9   TRUE  
 7 Richard Nixon California   258 day 3   TRUE  
 8 Richard Nixon California  -258 day 100 TRUE  
 9 Richard Nixon California   258 day 10  TRUE  
10 Richard Nixon California   258 day 100 TRUE
```

The problem with above output is that for Richard Nixon and for Bill Clinton there is one row too many where TRUE appears. My desired output is the following:

```
   name          state        num date    newcol
 1 Abe Lincoln   Oregon        87 day 99  FALSE 
 2 Bill Clinton  Indiana      123 day 2   TRUE
 3 Bill Clinton  Indiana      123 day 45  FALSE
 4 Bill Clinton  Indiana     -123 day 11  TRUE  
 5 George Bush   Florida       42 day 15  FALSE 
 6 Richard Nixon California  -258 day 9   TRUE  
 7 Richard Nixon California   258 day 3   TRUE  
 8 Richard Nixon California  -258 day 100 TRUE  
 9 Richard Nixon California   258 day 10  TRUE  
10 Richard Nixon California   258 day 100 FALSE
```

Notice how only rows where a mirrored match -mirrored match in the sense that the rows are duplicates except that they're additive inverses of one another for the column `num`. So im basically trying to identify all rows that match along the `name` and `state` variables and are additive inverses of each other along the `num` variable, with the condition that the additive inverses be unique -unique in the sense that `num` should only be considered an additive inverse of no more that one other row.

**For additional clarity if above explanation needs clarification, otherwise skip:**

So some process that loops through each row identifying the first row that meets the criteria of being a partial match (partial in the sense of absolute value / additive inverse) and then assigns a TRUE to those two rows and then moves on to the next observation and so on. For example, the code could begin with Abe Lincoln and run through each subsequent rows until a partially matched row is found, if no row is found then in the column `newcol` `FALSE` is the value that should be generated. Then it moves on to Bill Clinton, Indiana, 123 and runs through the rows to identify a partial match. The next row is NOT a partial match b/c 123 and 123 are not partial matches (they are full matches), but the following row is a partial match (123 and -123), resulting in the value of `TRUE` being generated for `newcol` for that observation as well as the partially matched row. Then it goes on to the third row (Bill Clinton, Indiana, 123). The important part by this step is that if a row already has a value for `newcol` the loop need not run through it. So for that row (the third row), the loop would skip the first row (with Abe Lincoln) b/c that already has a value of `FALSE` and it would skip the second row and 4th rows bc those two were already matched together, resulting in a `FALSE` for the third row b/c no remaining rows partially matched and the only partial match in the data frame was already matched with another inverse.

Comment: Please, unless you truly *need* and *use* all 25 packages within the `tidyverse`, just load the particular libraries you need. In this case, I suspect it is *just* `library(dplyr)`, but please double check. Why? While I *feel* (subjective) that the package is great as a meta-package to get all of the packages *installed*, I feel it is a bit sloppy to load a dozen or two packages you are never using. More specific to me: I don't need to install this meta package and do not want all 25 packages, so I don't have it, making it less likely that I'll try this question. (You want to make this easy.)

Comment: This is a huge amount of text and code. Couldn't you get it to the point a little better?

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the tip. That was the code I had copy pasted wholesale from the other post's solution I had mentioned. I updated to load `dplyr` instead.

Comment: @jay.sf It's a relatively complex and abstract request but feel free to edit it if you feel it can be conveyed in a more parsimonious fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may need to do a second grouping with `sign` to create another group of sequence that would help in identifying those rows that doesn't have a matching pair and update those to `FALSE`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(num = as.numeric(num), num1 = abs(num)) %>% 
     group_by(name, state, num1) %>% 
     mutate(newcol = n() > 1 & n_distinct(sign(num)) > 1) %>% 
     group_by(grp = sign(num), add = TRUE) %>% 
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
     group_by(name, state, num1, rn) %>% 
     mutate(newcol = replace(newcol, n()==1, FALSE)) %>%
     ungroup %>%
     select(-grp, -num1, -rn) %>% 
     arrange(name)
#A tibble: 10 x 5
#   name          state        num date    newcol
#   <chr>         <chr>      <dbl> <chr>   <lgl> 
# 1 Abe Lincoln   Oregon        87 day 99  FALSE 
# 2 Bill Clinton  Indiana      123 day 2   TRUE  
# 3 Bill Clinton  Indiana      123 day 45  FALSE 
# 4 Bill Clinton  Indiana     -123 day 11  TRUE  
# 5 George Bush   Florida       42 day 15  FALSE 
# 6 Richard Nixon California  -258 day 9   TRUE  
# 7 Richard Nixon California   258 day 3   TRUE  
# 8 Richard Nixon California  -258 day 100 TRUE  
# 9 Richard Nixon California   258 day 10  TRUE  
#10 Richard Nixon California   258 day 100 FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple working solution that will scale to the case where you have more than 1 extra non-mirrored observation. The basic idea is very simple: group, figure out the number of positives and negatives, order the observations so negatives proceed positives, determine whether negatives or positives are in excess, and then generate the TRUE/FALSE vector. Since the observations are ordered from neg to pos its straightforward to articulate what the outcome vector should look like for the cases where the negative values are unmatched or the positive cases are unmatched.

Code below:

```r
# Load data and libraries
library(dplyr)
name<-c("Richard Nixon", "Bill Clinton", "George Bush", "Richard Nixon", "Bill Clinton", "Richard Nixon", "Abe Lincoln","Richard Nixon", "Bill Clinton", "Richard Nixon")
state<-c("California", "Indiana", "Florida", "California", "Indiana", "California","Oregon","California", "Indiana", "California")
num<-c("-258", "123", "42", "258", "123", "-258", "87","258", "-123", "258")
date<-c("day 9", "day 2", "day 15", "day 3","day 45", "day 100", "day 99", "day 10", "day 11", "day 100")

# create dataframe
df <- data.frame(name, state, num, date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>% 
  mutate(num = as.numeric(num), # to work with
              row = row_number() # for reordering
         ) %>%
  group_by(name, state) %>% 
  arrange(num) %>% # we order the observations so that all the negs
                   # proceed the pos. 
  mutate(negs = max(0, table(sign(num))["-1"], na.rm=T), # get the number of negatives
         pos = max(0, table(sign(num))["1"], na.rm=T), # get the number of positives
         newcol = ifelse(negs > pos, # See which is in excess
                         c(rep(FALSE, negs[1]-pos[1]), rep(TRUE, 2*pos[1])),
                         c(rep(TRUE, 2*negs[1]), rep(FALSE, pos[1]-negs[1])))
         ) %>%
  arrange(name, row) %>%
  dplyr::select(-negs, -pos, -row)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#> # Groups:   name, state [4]
#>    name          state        num date    newcol
#>    <chr>         <chr>      <dbl> <chr>   <lgl> 
#>  1 Abe Lincoln   Oregon        87 day 99  FALSE 
#>  2 Bill Clinton  Indiana      123 day 2   TRUE  
#>  3 Bill Clinton  Indiana      123 day 45  FALSE 
#>  4 Bill Clinton  Indiana     -123 day 11  TRUE  
#>  5 George Bush   Florida       42 day 15  FALSE 
#>  6 Richard Nixon California  -258 day 9   TRUE  
#>  7 Richard Nixon California   258 day 3   TRUE  
#>  8 Richard Nixon California  -258 day 100 TRUE  
#>  9 Richard Nixon California   258 day 10  TRUE  
#> 10 Richard Nixon California   258 day 100 FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: This is a very clear and thorough explanation, thank you. It works well for the sample data but for some reason in my actual data there are occasional `TRUE` 's that should be `FALSE`'s so I accepted @akrun 's solution that worked with both my sample data and original data. But your solution is perfect for the sample provided - my apologies.