# Python: Find all additive inverse pairs in a list and remove them

Tags: python, math

I have a few lists that contain additive inverse pairs (adding both pairs give you zero), and for each list I am trying to remove those pairs.

Below are a few examples, where I am trying to go from this:

```
lst1 = [326, -326, 336, -336, 336]
lst2 = [-35, 35, 838, -838, 440]
lst3 = [544, -544, 544]
lst4 = [-25, 25, 32, -32, -32, 56, 79]
```

To this:

```
lst1 = [336]
lst2 = [440]
lst3 = [544]
lst4 = [-32, 56, 79]
```

You can see that in each list, the additive inverse pairs are removed, leaving the values that have no additive inverse, or the 1 extra non-mirrored value.

I wish I could share what I have tried, but I have been at it for a few days and any logic I come up with falls apart with the example in `lst4`.

I seem to have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665416/removing-pairs-of-additive-inverses) that yields exactly what I need, however it is written in R which I have no experience in, so I cannot understand the logic.

Any ideas on how I can overcome this?

Comment: I wonder if you could clarify whether the pairs need to be adjacent. For example what should the result be for an input of `[1, 2, -1]`?

Comment: Sorry they don't need to be adjacent, my example just presents them as such. In that example, I would expect the result to be ```[2]``` since 1 and -1 cancel each other out.

Comment: Also, what if there are more than one unpaired values? e.g. does `[-1, 0, 1, -1, -1]` become  `[-1, 0]` or `[-1, -1, 0]`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It should become ```[-1, -1, 0]``` since there is only one additive inverse pair, which is -1 and 1.

Comment: What should be the result of [0, 0, 0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of a running total of the elements you've seen in a (default)dictionary <sup>[documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)</sup>

A dictionary is a data structure that holds key-value pairs and allows quick lookup. In this instance, the elements of our input list will be our keys, and the values will be a count. You access values in a dictionary like so: `counter[key] = value`.

A *default* dictionary simply makes it so that when `key` is not already a part of the dictionary, it automatically generates a default value for it instead of throwing a [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError). So we define `counter = collections.defaultdict(int)`. The `int` specifies the default factory function for the values of yet-undefined keys.

Every time you see an unpaired number, you increment the counter for that number. Every time you find a number that has a pair in the counter, you decrement the counter for the pair. At the end, the keys of the counter will be the elements of your list, and the values will be the number of unpaired instances of that element were found, so we translate that into a list as required. Note that this will not preserve the order of the elements in the original list.

```
import collections

def filterInverse(lst):
    counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for num in lst:
        inverse = -num
        if counter[inverse] > 0:
            # Inverse was found previously in the counter
            # Decrement counter[inverse]
            counter[inverse] -= 1
            # And do nothing else with this number
        else: # Inverse wasn't found in the counter
            # This is an unpaired number so add it to the counter
            counter[num] += 1
    # Finally, go over the dict and return the keys whose values are nonzero
    # Repeat each item by its count
    # print(counter)
    rv = []
    for num, ct in counter.items():
        for _ in range(ct):
            rv.append(num)
    return rv
```

Running this with the inputs in your question and that we discussed in the comments,

```
>>> filterInverse(lst1)
Out: [336]

>>> filterInverse(lst2)
Out: [440]

>>> filterInverse(lst3)
Out: [544]

>>> filterInverse(lst4)
Out: [-32, 56, 79]

>>> lst5 = [-1, 0, 1, -1, -1]
>>> filterInverse(lst5)
Out: [-1, -1, 0]
```

---

If you're dead set against using `defaultdict`, you can get the same behavior by using a regular `dict.get(key, default)`<sup>[documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)</sup>:

```
counter = dict()

...
    ...
        if counter.get(inverse, 0) > 0:
            # Inverse was found previously in the counter
            # Decrement counter[inverse]
            counter[inverse] = counter.get(inverse, 0) - 1
            # And do nothing else with this number
        else: # Inverse wasn't found in the counter
            # This is an unpaired number so add it to the counter
            counter[num] = counter.get(num, 0) + 1
    ...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to keep track of additive pairs as well as handle duplicates:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain
def remove_additive_pairs(sequence: list) -> list:
    """ Remove additive pairs from given sequence. """
    result = defaultdict(list)
    
    for element in sequence:
        if -element in result:
            del result[-element]
        else:
            result[element].append(element)
            
    return list(chain.from_iterable(result.values()))

>>> lst5 = [-25, 25, 32, -25, 25, 32]
>>> for seq in [lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4, lst5]:
        print(remove_additive_pairs(seq))

[336]
[440]
[544]
[-32, 56, 79]
[32, 32]
```

Of course you can do the same without importing `itertools.chain` or `collections.defaultdict`:

```
def chain(args):
    for lst in args:
        for elem in lst:
            yield elem

            
def remove_additive_pairs(sequence: list) -> list:
    """ Remove additive pairs from given sequence. """
    result = dict()
    
    for element in sequence:
        if -element in result:
            del result[-element]
        else:
            result.setdefault(element, []).append(element)
            
    return list(chain(result.values()))
```

---

`defaultdict` is a `dict-like` container that can provide `default` values for `missing keys`.
For example:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d[5]
[]
```

So defining `defaultdict(list)` ensures that when we get a number whose inverse is not already in the keys, we can add that number as a `key` to the dictionary, as well as `append` it to a `list` in its values in one step.

Comment: This will fail if the output should have duplicate values for example with input like: `lst4 = [-25, 25, 32, -25, 25, 32]` I would expect output of `[32, 32]`

Comment: I see, let me modify.

Comment: @Mark could you check if this works for you?

Comment: I think there is a little ambiguity in the question about if the order matters. What do you expect from `filterInverse([1, 2, -1])`? I think if should be `[1, 2, -1]`, but you might read the problem differently and arrive at `[2]`.

Comment: @Mark Indeed, as the order is not mentioned, for your example I would arrive at `[2]`, guess we'd have to wait for the OP to clear things out. Btw, `filterInverse` one is nice. +1

Comment: Looks like your instincts are correct here. Nice job.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Thanks for the solution. I'm not too familiar with defaultdict. Can you explain why you first defined ```result = defaultdict(list)```?

Comment: Added. Let me know if its clear.  You can find more about [defaultdict here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Answer (score 0):

First, count how many times each value appears in the list. Then iterate through the list, either populating a new list or throwing the value away and decrementing the counter of the inverse value.

```py
from collections import Counter

def remove_inverses(lst):
  value_counts = Counter(lst)
  result = []
  for element in lst:
    if value_counts.get(-element):
      value_counts[-element] -= 1
    else:
      result.append(element)
  return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the awesome `collections.Counter`:

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import repeat

def remove_opposite_pairs(seq):
    dplus = Counter(seq)
    dminus = Counter(-x for x in seq)
    for x,n in (dplus - dminus).items():
        yield from repeat(x, n)

lsts = [[326, -326, 336, -336, 336],
        [-35, 35, 838, -838, 440],
        [544, -544, 544],
        [-25, 25, 32, -32, -32, 56, 79],
        [-1, 0, 1, -1, -1]]

for l in lsts:
    print(list(remove_opposite_pairs(l)))
# [336]
# [440]
# [544]
# [-32, 56, 79]
# [-1, -1]
```

Note the weird behaviour on 0, because 0 is its own opposite. I could fix it, but first you need to edit your question to specify exactly how to handle 0.

Here is a possible fix:

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import repeat

def remove_opposite_pairs(seq):
    dplus = Counter(seq)
    dminus = Counter(-x for x in seq)
    for x,n in (dplus - dminus).items():
        yield from repeat(x, n)
    if dplus[0] % 2 == 1:
        yield 0

lsts = [[-1, 0, 1, -1, -1],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]

for l in lsts:
    print(list(remove_opposite_pairs(l)))
# [-1, -1, 0]
# []
# [0]
```